# Uable to post to mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Hey guys i am new to MEAN stack and i am trying to make a post request using Postman but it throws the error username not defined.. Connection with mongodb is done successfully and and works fine but it prompts undefined identifier username for user.username I'm unable to debug the error. I tried throwing post request using browser also but didn't help.

Code:

```
user.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new schema({
username : {type:String,lowercase:true,required:true,unique:true},
password : {type:String,required:true},
email : {type:String,required:true,unique:true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);

index.js(server.js)

//Variables------------------------------
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./app/models/user');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//---------------------------------------

//Configuration--------------------------
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing 
application/x-www-form-
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.use(morgan('dev'));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/development',function(err){
 if(err){
 console.log('Not connected '+err);
}else{
 console.log('Connected to db');
}
});

//----------------------------------------

//Routes----------------------------
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World with a post number'+port);
});

app.get('/home',function(req,res){
res.send('Hello from home');
});

app.post('/users',function(req,res){
var user = new User();
//res.send('This is working'+user);
user.username=req.body.username;
user.password=req.body.password;
user.email   =req.body.email;
//user.save()
res.send("username "+user.username);
res.send("password"+user.password);
res.send("email"+user.email);
res.send('User Registered!!!');
});

//-----------------------------------

app.listen(port,function(){
console.log('Running the server');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var user = new User({
  username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    email: req.body.email,
});
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code ... now it does not throw any error but still collection is empty

Comment: Don't forget to save the object as user.save()

Comment: i did that the problem was with Postman ...... got i working finally thanks

Answer (score 1):

The updated code which defines 'User'

```
var user = new User({
  username: req.body.username,
  password: req.body.password,
  email: req.body.email,
});
```

shouldn't have a comma after `req.body.email`.

You should also be getting the error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

in the console because you have multiple `res.send` lines in `app.post()`; use only one.

As Sandeep mentioned, don't forget to uncomment `user.save()`.
I did that with your code, submitted text from the three input fields, and was able to get a document in my collection 'users.'